# 14.10 backup folder to another drive in the same machine?

Tags: backup

I'm new to Linux so apologize in advance for the basic question.  I have two drives installed in this machine.  It is essentially poor man's RAID - the second drive is a copy of the first.  There is a very small app and database that is a folder called /home/xxx.  I want to copy the contents of this folder from the first drive to the second drive on a schedule say once an hour.

In Windows, I would use something like SyncToy to do this and it would be very easy to setup.  I'm assuming I can do this easily in Ubuntu as well.

This machine recently failed and having the backup disk really saved our butts.  However, I didn't set up the backup.  I think it just used the built-in backup software but I have no idea how to tell it to copy to a different drive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set up a script (like a BAT file in Windows) that issues an `rsync` command. The `rsync` command will synchronize disk 2 with disk 1 (and not the other way around). Make this script executable (with the `chmod` command) and test it. Open your `cron` file (`crontab -e`) and schedule your rsync script to run at every hour.

You could put the rsync command in the cron file directly, but I prefer to have cron call a script so you can easily add more commands if necessary.